# Discrepancy of company names due to punctuation in sql table

Tags: sql

I have one table column name 'Company' contains more than 10,000 records. Some of the company values is like "trail co ltd" vs "trail co., ltd". I need to capturing all company with same name however separated by punctuations using sql query. 
Could anyone share the sample sql query to get the list of the values from table?

```
 Sample data: Column name Company values - "trail co ltd" and "trail co., ltd".
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Sample data: Column name 'Company' values - "trail co ltd" and  "trail co., ltd". I want to get whatever company values having the same name with punctuations and with out punctuations.

Comment: Not as a comment. Edit your question instead. Don't forget proper formatting. (Tip: when editing, mark the sample data and click `{}`.)

Answer (score 0):

can u try this

```
SELECT COMPANY FROM TABLENAME WHERE COMPANY in ('trail co ltd','trail co., ltd');
```

If u want to get count saperatly u can try this

```
SELECT COUNT(COMPANY) AS comp_count  FROM TABLENAME  WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%trail co ltd%'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(COMPANY) FROM TABLENAME  WHERE COMPANY LIKE '%trail co., ltd%'
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually i want to get how many companies are having same name( with &without puctuations) from table?      

Eg: Tata co ltd vs Tata co., ltd. we know that both companies are same. But our application considered this names as different. That why i need to get the lists from table and change those to same name. I do know how many companies are having like this in table. So that i need the sample query.

Comment: do u want to change all column having "trail co., ltd" to "trail co ltd" or count all company having name "'trail co ltd'" and "trail co., ltd" in a same query separately?

Comment: In my table table column name company having more than 10,000 company names. I found only one company having the below format.I do know how many companies are having the same name(example: "tata co ltd" vs "tata co., ltd",etc...) with punctuation on table(company column). I just want to get the company names from table whatever companies having the same name with punctuation using sql query .

Format: "trail co., ltd" vs "trail co ltd"